# Extract a forwarded domain name and output the result into html using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dns, extract, forwarding

I would like to extract a forwarded domain name and output the result in an HTML field using JavaScript. Something similar to:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the parameter a variable name
var dynamicContent = getParameterByName('domain');

 $(document).ready(function() {

    // Check if the URL parameter matches
    if (dynamicContent == 'example1') {
        $('#example1').show();
    } 
    // Check if the URL parameter matches
    else if (dynamicContent == 'example') {
        $('#nothing to see').show();
    }
```

But that method calls for each domain to be set with a different parameter in the forwarded domains, eg example.com/page.html?domain=example1, example.net/page.html?domain=example2.

What I have is: example.com, example.org example.net, and others, and have them all forwarded to a single example.dev webpage.

What I need, is a method to extract the forwarded domain name that was used to get to my example.dev destination site and output it within an html field/property using JavaScript, without having multiple parameters set in the forwarding addresses. Is it possible to determine which typed-in source domain was used in this instance, and what would be the proper code to implement?

Comment: Trying to read between lines .... correct me pelase you wish to catch ther refferer domain that was forwarded to eacmple.dev domain. if that is the case then we just need to mix match couple of native tools

Comment: var referrer = document.referrer; gives URI which we will then let domain = (new URL(URI)); let host = domain.hostname; this would give you you basics of which domain the link came from  
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer  
 and    https://w3collective.com/get-domain-name-url-javascript/